# Table - Count Column

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that coverts JSON from an API and creates a table output.
How would I TOTAL (add or count) the column 'TotalEndpoints' and display the total number of Enpoints?

Here is the creation of the table

```
(Invoke-RestMethod @Params).Sites | Format-Table SiteName,SiteId,TotalEndpoints
```

[image: Output of Powershell script]

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select-Object` for manipulating objects. Use `Format-Table` only as the last step for the actual output.

```
$sites = (Invoke-RestMethod @Params).Sites |
         Select-Object SiteName, SiteId, TotalEndpoints

$total = @($sites | Select-Object -Expand TotalEndpoints).Count

$sites | Format-Table
"Total: $total"
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out.

```
$value = 0
$t = foreach($Sites in $test)
{
$value = $value + $Sites.TotalEndpoints
}
Write-Host $value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will get the job done. You can also try [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-5.1) if you want to avoid duplicating for-loops for common calculations.

Try something like this:

```
$siteData = (Invoke-RestMethod @Params).Sites
$siteData | Format-Table SiteName,SiteId,TotalEndpoints
$GrandTotalEndpoints = ($siteData | Measure-Object -sum -property TotalEndpoints).Sum
Write-Host $GrandTotalEndpoints
```